# Include image inside a variable

Tags: php, image, variables, addition

I expect this is a dumb question but I'm not the best when it comes to php. I want to add an image inside the below variable, what do I need to do?

```
$usermessage = 

"
Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src="images/wbf-logo.png" />

";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use single Quote '

```
$usermessage = "
Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src='images/wbf-logo.png' />

";
```

Or Add backslash

```
$usermessage = "
Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src=\"images/wbf-logo.png\" />

";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, escape the double quote in the image tag

```
"
Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src=\"images/wbf-logo.png\" />

";
```

OR

```
"
Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src='images/wbf-logo.png' />

";
```

Answer (score 0):

try as follows

```
"
Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src=\"images/wbf-logo.png\" />

";
```

OR

```
'
Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src="images/wbf-logo.png" />

';
```

Answer (score 0):

Magic slashes. And i replaced \n with `<br />`.

```
$usermessage = "Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
<br />
Address 1
Address 2
<img src=\"images/wbf-logo.png\" />

";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$usermessage = '
Thank you for joining our mailing list <br />
We hope to see you very soon!
<br />
Address 1
Address 2
<img src="images/wbf-logo.png" />';
```

Comment: use single quote its faster than double quote but remember everything inside single quote is simply string... \n will not break your line in html ..

Answer (score 0):

Just add backslash to protect double quotes, like this :

```
$usermessage = "Thank you for joining our mailing list

We hope to see you very soon!
\n
Address 1
Address 2
<img src=\"images/wbf-logo.png\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add backslash there :

Example:

```
<img src=\"images/wbf-logo.png\" />;
```